# React controlled input with debounce

Tags: reactjs, react-native, debouncing

How to clear value in a controlled input using debounce?
//Debounce function

```
function useDebounce(func, waitTimeMs, dependencies = []) {
  return useCallback(debounce(func, waitTimeMs), dependencies)
}

export function debounce(func, wait){
  let timeout

  return function executedFunction(...args) {
    const later = () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout)
      func(...args)
    }

    clearTimeout(timeout)
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait)
  }
}
```

I have a functional(child) component to get input to do a search query

```
export default function ContentFilter({
  onSearchChange, value
}) {
  /** debounced search input handler */
  const handleSearchChange = useDebounce(onSearchChange, 200)

  return (
    <>
      <InputSearch
        placeholder='Search Content'
        onChange={e => handleSearchChange(e.target.value)}
        type='search'
      />
    </>
  )
}
```

in the parent component, I am using this component to get the value of the input field and doing the search with my backend. In some cases, I need to clear the search field value programmatically. Since this is not a controlled component I am not able to clear the value in the textbox.

Comment: Can you pass a value prop to InputSearch component?

Comment: if I pass props value into InputSearch when I enter any value the input focus out because of the debounce